# Query de una tabla desde otro servidorsql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

pregunta hay alguna otra forma de enlazar dos servidores sql server, pero que no sea por Linked Server? Ya que actualmente no dejan usar los linked server.. y quiero consultar una tabla que esta en otro servidor. Algunas sugerencias son bienvenidas..

Saludos!!

Comment: Si necesitas datos de otro servidor, habla con el DBA para que te deje usar linked server.  Si el DBA no te deja, dile a tu jefe que el DBA no lo permite y pasa a la siguiente tarea. Si tu jefe aún quiere datos de otros servidores, él hablará con el DBA. Si te asignan de nuevo la tarea, eso ya estará resuelto, y si no, regresa al paso 1. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero esa no es una opción viable. Igual muchas gracias, saludos..

Comment: Si tienes una conexión de lectura del servidor remoto puedes intentar utilizar alguna herramienta de ETL, por ejemplo SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), donde la aplicación se conecta a la tabla que necesites y luego puede depositar la información en el servidor en el que la necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Tu puedes considerar usar OPENROWSET para consultar datos en otro servidor. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
'SQLNCLI',
'Server=nombre_servidor_remoto;Database=nombre_base_datos_remota;Uid=tu_nombre_usuario_sql;Pwd=tu_contrasena;',
'SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla_remota'
);
```

En este ejemplo uso [SQL Server Native Client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=50402?1558859051) como driver. Y para que funcione debes habilitar "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries".

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Para ver más ejemplos, visita [este artículo](https://www.sqlshack.com/querying-remote-data-sources-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Si no tiene posibilidad de usar Linked Servers, es poco probable que tenga acceso a esta opción.

Comment: Es la única otra alternativa que le puedo dar a Noé.